# Using a Webview in a modal NSSheet

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit

I am having an issue similiar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4164407). I would like to have a webview in an NSSheet in which I am doing some authentication to retrieve an API token.

I created a new `NSWindowController` subclass with a corresponding xib file. This is how I am starting the NSSheet:

```
- (IBAction)startAuthentication:(NSButton *)sender {
    self.authController = [[AuthenticationWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"AuthenticationWindow"];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet:self.authController.window
                                   modalForWindow:[self.exportManager window]
                                    modalDelegate:self
                                   didEndSelector:@selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                                      contextInfo:nil];
}
```

In the windowDidLoad callback of this authenticationWindowController I am directing the webview to the URL:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [[self.webView mainFrame]loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:authURL]];
}
```

It looks great at first sight: if I press the button, the `startAuthentication` action method is called and the new window is animated into the parent window and the authURL is loaded. The website is displayed correctly with its HTML form containing two input fields (username and password).

The problem is, that I can click on the page and it works, however if I am trying to click into one textfield, so that this field gets focus it does not work. No cursor appears in the text field of the website's form and after each keystroke I hear the NSBeep() sound.

I did some research on this topic and I found two references:

- [How do I use a WebView in a modal dialog?](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/Apr/msg02260.html)
- [Cocoa topics: the case of the modal WebView](http://www.dejal.com/blog/2007/01/cocoa-topics-case-modal-webview)

What kind of puzzles me is that there is the [Facebook Exporter for Aperture](https://github.com/streeter/facebook-aperture-exporter) Plugin, which shows exactly what I want: a webview in a modal sheet. However I cannot find out what they are making differently . In the Facebook Exporter I have not found any code interacting with the run loops directly.

**My questions**

1. Is this a known problem with webviews in modal sheets?
2. Are the problems explained in the two references still there?
3. How can I get this working? I do not understand when to switch the runloop mode for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no general problem with this and I just tried it out again. must be some code besides this? can you narrow it down to the sheet? btw: my sample:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3753090/test2.zip

---

BUT all that said, modal runmode and webviews / timers / networking isnt very waterproof :)
because: when you go modal via one of the convenience methods in NSApp, the runloop is only run in a very limited way. :/

Comment: this answers 1 and maybe 2 but not 3 yet -- plz provide a sample project we can fix :D It just works here... and it might not be related to the sheet!?

Comment: I just made a sample project. It is an Aperture exporter plugin, so I was not sure if the plugin window itself is run in a runloop in modal mode. However the minimalistic sample seems to work. I am still investigating.

Comment: OK - Now it works. All I did was deleting the XIB and start the XIB over from scratch. Very many thanks to looking into it.