# How to enable modaldialog in Cocoa WebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

When I'm loading a `HTML` page that contains `ModalDialog` in `WebView`,no popup window is opened at all.That same `HTML` page works without issue in `Safari`.So anyone can solve it?

Here is the code:

```
- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request{
NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 300) styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
[window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
WebView *webView = [[WebView alloc] init];
[webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
window.contentView = webView;
[webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:webView];
return webView;
}

- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewModalDialogWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request{
return [self webView:sender createWebViewWithRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewRunModal:(WebView *)sender{
[sender.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}

- (void)webViewShow:(WebView *)sender{
[sender.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}

- (void)webViewClose:(WebView *)sender{

[sender.window close];

}
```

Comment: Found a similar thread at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164407/using-webview-in-a-modal-nswindow-not-working). Kindly check if the solution proposed in this thread fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks,this link gives me some ideas to solve it.And here is the code

Answer (score 0):

```
 #pragma -mark -WebView Delegate

- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewWithRequest:    (NSURLRequest *)request{
NSUInteger windowStyleMask = NSClosableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSTitledWindowMask;
_webWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 300) styleMask:windowStyleMask backing:NSBackingStoreNonretained defer:YES];
[_webWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
WebView* newWebView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:[_webWindow contentRectForFrameRect:_webWindow.frame]];
[newWebView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
[[newWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
[_webWindow setContentView:newWebView];
[_webWindow center];
[_webWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

return newWebView;

 }


 - (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewModalDialogWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request{

return [self webView:sender createWebViewWithRequest:request];
 }


 - (void)webViewRunModal:(WebView *)sender{

[sender.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

 }

- (void)webViewShow:(WebView *)sender{

[sender.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

}

- (void)webViewClose:(WebView *)sender{
[sender.window close];
}
```